# Displaying dataSource table waits for mouseEvent

Tags: angular, service, mouseevent

I am programming a web app with Angular 8, and, at some point, I need to load data from the Backend  using a service (without refreshing the page). 
For instance, on this screenshot :[image: screenshot]

When I click on a row from "Activos para picking", I want to load the table "Información pieza" with info from an asset (taken with a Service). So I see that the dataSource of the table "Información pieza" loads (in the console) but, in order to see the data on the table, it seems that the app waits for the next "mouseEvent" (for example if I click on another row, or if the cursor moves over the header of the table). It only does it when I call a service, if I just want to fetch the data from a local variable, the table updates instantly.

I really don't know where it's coming from, so I ask you if you have any idea.

Here's the html code of this page, tell me if you need more precision.

```html
<div>
 <div>
  <table mat-table class="lmat-elevation-z8 container-fluid"  [dataSource]="activosPicking" matSort matSortActive="id" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
   
   <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let activo" class="mat-column-vinCode">{{activo[0]}}</td>
   </ng-container>
   
   <ng-container matColumnDef="albaran">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Albarán</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let activo" class="mat-column-vinCode">{{activo[1]}}</td>
   </ng-container>
   
   <ng-container matColumnDef="pn">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>PN</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let activo" class="mat-column-vinCode">{{activo[2]}}</td>
   </ng-container>
   
   <ng-container matColumnDef="ubicacion">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Ubicación</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let activo" class="mat-column-vinCode">{{activo[3]}}</td>
   </ng-container>
   
   <ng-container matColumnDef="unidades">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Unidades</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let activo" class="mat-column-vinCode">{{activo[4]}}</td>
   </ng-container>
   
   <tr mat-header-row  *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
   <tr mat-row  class="element-row" id="news" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
   (click)="getRecord(row[0])" [ngClass]="{'highlight': id== row[0]}"></tr>
   
  </table>
 </div>

 <div>
  <table class ="table  table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>PN</th>
     <th>Lote</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let activo of clickedActivo" >
     <td>{{activo[0]}}</td>
     <td>{{activo[1]}}</td>
     <td>{{activo[2]}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

I also get this message in the console, I don't know if it is related...

> zone.js:1832 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a
>   scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as
>   'passive' to make the page more responsive. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Comment: may I ask where/how I can get to the kt-portlet directive? Should I create one by myself or it already exists?

Comment: Hi @MohammadShadmehr, it comes from a paid template, but you can run the code without it (simply using the two tables) and the issue still exists. In fact, I4ñ going to simplify my code example in the question

Answer (score 0):

In the TypeScript file, when updating your dataSource, try doing a reinitialization of the property by using the spread operator for arrays.
For example, instead of

`this.service.get().subscribe(arrayResponse => this.dataservice = arrayResponse)`

try

`this.service.get().subscribe(arrayResponse => this.dataservice = [...arrayResponse])`

(notice `arrayResponse` vs `[...arrayResponse]`.

Let me know if this fixed it. Buena suerte!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer Dragos. It doesn't seem to work unfortunately...

Comment: I added a console error message int the originl post that could be related

Comment: Hmm, ok. Do you think you can reproduce this in a StackBlitz environment (https://stackblitz.com/)? If so, can you do it and share it here?

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce it in Syackblitz, but I don't get the issue on the Stackblitz environment, I think it has something to do with the Service